# Understanding a proof that $\delta(x-x') = \mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x\, \theta(x-x')$

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics

A solution to an exercise in *Principles of Quantum Mechanics*:

> [image]

My question concerns the leap

> [image]

This is apparently an application of Integration by Parts; however, it seems to me it is conflating
$$
\int g(x)\,\mathrm{d}\theta(x-x')
$$

with

$$
\int g(x) \theta'(x-x')\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

which is the form required for us to able to apply Integration by Parts.
Is this not the case?

Comment: are we to assume that $x'$ represents a constant in this case and that $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function?

Comment: @HenryLee Yes.  Also, $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta "function" (technically a distribution).

Comment: Writing $d\theta$ is fine, but a little confusing. If we ignore that 'simplification', we have $\frac{d\theta}{dx} dx$ instead of $d\theta$, and then the integration by parts works as (I think) you want it to.

Comment: Which book is this from? And is there a definition of a test function in the book? (not always the case in physics books). Requiring test functions to either vanish or decay fast at infinity (Schwarz functions) makes life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Riemann-Stieltjes integral**

*Definition.* The Riemann–Stieltjes integral of a real-valued function $f$ of a real variable on the interval $[a,b]$ with respect to another real-to-real function $\alpha$ is denoted by
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}\alpha(x).$$
The definition of the Riemann–Stieltjes integral can be found [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/m321/integralDef.pdf).

*Lemma 1.* Given an $\alpha(x)$ which is continuously differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}\alpha(x) = \int_a^b f(x)\alpha'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

*Lemma 2.* Let $f$ be a Riemann-Stieltjes integrable function with respect to $\alpha$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Then $\alpha$ be a Riemann-Stieltjes integrable function with respect to $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ and
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}\alpha(x)=\left[\alpha(x)f(x)\right]_{a}^{b}-\int_a^b \alpha(x) \, \mathrm{d}f(x).$$

A proof of this theorem can be found [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-formula-for-integration-by-parts-of-riemann-stieltjes-in).

**Analyzing the leap**

Choose $f(x) =g(x)$ and $\alpha(x)=\Theta(x-x')$. By Lemma 2,

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \, \mathrm{d}\Theta(x-x') &= \left[\Theta(x-x')g(x)\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Theta(x-x') \, \mathrm{d}g(x).
\end{align}$$

If we let $g(x)$ be continuously differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$, by Lemma 1 we get
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \, \mathrm{d}\Theta(x-x') &= \left[\Theta(x-x')g(x)\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Theta(x-x')g'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Okay well in terms of understanding why this is the case, visualising it graphically, $\theta(x-x')$ is going to be a step from $0$ to $1$ at the point $x=x'$. Now clearly this is a discontinuity but we can visualise this as a vertical line i.e. infinite gradient at the point $x=x'$. Now if we are to plot the gradient of $\theta$ we would see that it is clearly $0$ everywhere other than at this point as it is a constant function over the two domains. As for the integral you mentioned, it is completely fine to use it in that form. the dirac delta is commonly defined as:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\delta(x-x')dx=g(x')$$
so bearing this in mind:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)d\theta(x-x')=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\frac{d\theta(x-x')}{dx}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\delta(x-x')dx=g(x')$$
which is effectively what this is proving

Comment: What justifies the step $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \frac{d\theta(x-x')}{dx}dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \delta(x-x')dx$?

Comment: Henry Lee: Unless I'm missing something: it seems like you are assuming that the statement we are trying to prove is true, and then using it circularly as the last step in your proof.

Comment: @user1770201 this is not a rigorous prove but was just intended to explain the steps in the proof you provided and explain where they originate from